# Input Box Drop Down

Tags: jquery, input, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create an input field that begins listing possible names when the user starts typing. Almost exactly like "google suggestions". So the possible matches of what a user is typing begin to appear and narrow as the user types more letters...

What is this called? And what would be the best way to approach it? AJAX? Just javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you need is jquery autocomplete

1. [jquery auto complete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)
   or for asp.net ajax toolkit
2. [ASP.net ajax toolkit autocomplete](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx)

hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

It's known as Autocomplete or Autosuggest

Try Jquery [autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete)

Answer (score 2):

Easiest thing i think is just to use jquery. http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ You don't have to use ajax, you can preload the data in a list if you want to.

Comment: and by the way how much data are you assuming to preload ?

Comment: @Billa Ustad i couldn't say for him, but he wasn't sure about ajax. So it seems like he could most likely just preload the data into a list instead of putting more load on the server.

Comment: @Billa Ustad - if its cities, then i would say use googles api or any other map API. I doubt it's going to be cities. If it's countries or states, then yea preload it.